# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'featureCarousel'

Tags: jquery, slider

Trying to implement a jQuery carousel at https://www.advisorbackgroundcheck.com/index2.php ( a copy of the index from the production site) 
, on this page I made sure I had connected everything the css files , JS library etc and it thows out an "Uncaught TypeError" on line 20 .

However I have the same demo working at https://www.advisorbackgroundcheck.com/slider.html

which works like a charm , maybe there is conflict at the homepage not sure with what .

or am I missing anthing Any suggestions  ?

Comment: please post the offending code.

Comment: It's a curious thing. After debugging for a bit, I can say that $.fn.featureCarousel is undefined, and after inputting the minified JavaScript into the console, an attempt to make a carousel of the element in question alerts me that $().first() isn't defined either.